# string returns empty if it contains a $ sign in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the example below, the amount is retrieved correctly, unless it has a $ sign in the front (ex: $25.00),in which case it always return an empty string.

HTML:

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" id="dailyCost" placeholder=" $ Cost p/ Day">
```

JavaScipt:

```
var amount = document.getElementById("dailyCost").value;
```

EITHER / OR

```
var amount $("#dailyCost").val();
```

Comment: The field is `type="number"`, `'$'` is not a number.

Comment: Please "USD" or "$" right before the input, so that it's more obvious the users don't have to type it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need change the type value of your input, to text for example, because $ will give a [NaN](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_number_nan.asp) response

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="dailyCost" placeholder=" $ Cost p/ Day">
```